# How can I tell the compiler not to create a temporary object?

Tags: c++, oop

I'm changing an old routine that used to take an integer parameter so that it now takes a const reference to an object. I was hoping that the compiler would tell me where the function is called from (because the parameter type is wrong), but the object has a constructor that takes an integer, so rather than failing, the compiler creates a temporary object, passing it the integer, and passes a reference to that to the routine. Sample code:

```
class thing {
  public:
    thing( int x ) {
        printf( "Creating a thing(%d)\n", x );
    }
};

class X {
  public:
    X( const thing &t ) {
        printf( "Creating an X from a thing\n" );
    }
};


int main( int, char ** ) {
    thing a_thing( 5 );
    X an_x( 6 );
    return 1;
}
```

I want the `X an_x( 6 )` line to **not compile**, because there is no `X` constructor that takes an `int`. But it does compile, and the output looks like:

```
Creating a thing(5)
Creating a thing(6)
Creating an X from a thing
```

How can I keep the `thing( int )` constructor, but disallow the temporary object?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `explicit` keyword in the thing constructor.

```
class thing {
public:
    explicit thing( int x ) {
        printf( "Creating a thing(%d)\n", x );
    }
};
```

This will prevent the compiler from implicitly calling the thing constructor when it finds an integer.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-in-c-mean

Comment: Perfect - I have been writing C++ code for about 15 years, and have never heard of the explicit keyword. Thanks!

Comment: Related question - can you use the explicit keyword on a method that's not a constructor?

Comment: No, explicit is only for constructors. You can't stop implicit conversions for parameters in other methods.

Answer (score 1):

The `explicit` keyword works perfectly in my example, but I realized later that my *real world* code was failing on an overloaded method, not the constructor. (My fault for asking a question that was similar to, but not the same as, my actual problem.) As Mark Ransom pointed out in the comments on the accepted answer, `explicit` only works on constructors. I came up with a workaround that solved my problem, so I figured I'd post it here. New sample code:

```
class thing {
  public:
    thing( int x ) {
        printf( "Creating a thing(%d)\n", x );
    }
};

class X {
  public:
    void do_something( const thing &t ) {
        printf( "Creating an X from a thing\n" );
    }
};


int main( int, char ** ) {
    thing a_thing( 5 );
    X an_x;
    an_x.do_something( 6 );
    return 1;
}
```

This code shows the same output as the original code, but I can't use `explicit` to fix it. Instead, I added a private method that takes an `int`:

```
  private:
    void do_something( int x );
```

Now, the compiler doesn't create the temporary object, it gives an error because I am trying to call a private method from outside the class.

Comment: in c++1x, we will be able to write void do_something( int x ) = delete; already works in gcc svn trunk.

Comment: @Graeme Perrow. Explicit should still work in the case you outline. That is, making the thing constructor explicit will result in a compiler error. Is it because you don't have access to the thing class to modify it?

@litb have we started calling it C++1x now? Did I miss the memo?

Comment: @zdan: you're right. I was thinking about how to modify the X class and wasn't thinking about modifying the thing class. That does what I need. Thanks!